# ActiveAdmin "f.inputs, except: [:field]" doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

Formtastic has a great tool to prevent certain fields on a model showing up, used as so:

```
f.inputs, :except => [:featured, :something_for_admin_only]
```

ActiveAdmin claims to be derived from Formtastic, but it seems that ":except" doesn't work.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to remove comma (`,`) after `f.inputs`:

```
f.inputs :except => [:featured, :something_for_admin_only]
```

Comment: Thanks! So simple in the end!