# Rails ActiveAdmin “f.inputs, except: [:belong_to field]” doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I wanted to use except command to prevent a foreign key field (belong_to) given in this link:[ActiveAdmin "f.inputs, except: [:field]" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943514/activeadmin-f-inputs-except-field-doesnt-work)
like this:

```
f.inputs, :except => [:featured, :something_for_admin_only]
```

It works with other fields except foreign key, now how can I do that for foreign key fields?

Answer (score 3):

Passing string instead of symbol worked for me:

```
f.inputs except: ['user', :event_name]
```